# sending email to multiple recipients via mailjet error

Tags: php, email, mailjet

I'm having this code to send an email to multiple recipients which works fine with static data

```
$subject = 'test';
include("mailjet/php-mailjet-v3.class.php");
$mj = new Mailjet( 'api', 'secret' );
$params = array(
    "method" => "POST",
    "FromEmail" => "order@domain.com",
    "FromName" => "sender name",
    "Subject" => "subject here",
    "Html-Part" => "<html><table><tr><td colspan='2'>message</td></tr></table></html>",
    "Text-Part" => "message",
    'Recipients' => [
    [
        'Email' => "passenger1@mailjet.com",
        'Name' => "passenger 1"
    ],
    [
        'Email' => "passenger2@mailjet.com",
        'Name' => "passenger 2"
    ]
]
);
$result = $mj->send($params);
echo $mj->_response_code; //200 success
```

but when I use dynamic data in this way i get error 500 and email wasn't sent

```
//an array of emails from the db
$user[] = 'user1@mail.com';
$user[] = 'user2@mail.com';
foreach ($user as $email){
$to .= "[
    'Email' => '".$email."'
],";
}
```

and change the Recipients to:

```
'Recipients' => [ $to ]
```

when I echo $to I get this

```
[ 'Email' => 'user1@mail.com' ],[ 'Email' => 'user2@mail.com' ],
```

Can you help me find the error in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$to=[];
foreach ($emails as $email){
    $to[] = [
        'Email' => $email
    ];
}

"Recipients" => $to
```